# PostgreSQL/SQL query optimization

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

So, i have log table with something about 8M records. Because of programming error it happened that there are more than 1 record for company within same date. Now, what i need is to delete all records from this log for each company for same date except latest (which has max id). Count of records to be deleted approximately 300K.

The fastest and easiest thing that i tried is this

```
delete from indexing_log where id not in (
select max(id)
from indexing_log
group by company_id,
"date"
)
```

But this query is taking enormous time (about 3 days) on production server (which for some reason doesn't have ssd drive). I tried all ways that i know and need some advice. How can it be faster?

UPDATE
I decided to do it in bucket way through celery task.

Comment: Add an explain plan.  Can you define enormous time?

Comment: In addition to providing the explain plan what version of PostgreSQL are you on?

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
delete from indexing_log as l
where
    exists
    (
        select *
        from indexing_log as i
        where i.id < l.id and i.company_id = l.company_id and i.dt = l.dt
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Dump the distinct rows to a temporary table

```
create temporary table t as
select distinct on (company_id, "date") *
from indexing_log
order by company_id, "date", id desc;
```

Truncate the original

```
truncate table indexing_log;
```

Since the table is now empty use the opportunity to do an instantaneous `vacuum`:

```
vacuum full indexing_log;
```

Move the rows from the temporary to the original

```
insert into indexing_log
select *
from t;
```

Comment: `distinct on (id ...)` is pointless if `id` is unique. Maybe `distinct on (company_id, "date")`. Also `order by company_id, "date", id desc` - otherwise it wont work

Comment: Don't you mean `select max(id), company_id, date from ... group by company_id, date`? otherwise I have to read about `distinct on`

Comment: @Roman Yes, you and Igor are right. I corrected it. In this case the `distinct on` has the great advantage of returning all columns of the row.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be fast. Now i'll try it on production.

Comment: Insert operation is very heavy, because of number of rows which left much bigger than the deleted ones.

Answer (score 1):

Truncate Table should be much quicker. But there you cannot say "delete everything except..." 
If it is possible with your data you could write a procedure for that, save your Max IDs into a temptable, trucate the table and write your temptable back. For PostgreSQL the syntax is slighly different (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-selectinto.html)

```
SELECT * from indexing_log 
INTO #temptable 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT max(id)
    FROM indexing_log
    GROUP BY company_id,
    "date")
```

Answer (score 1):

`Not Exists` is sometimes faster than `Not in`

```
delete from indexing_log 
where not exists (select 1
                    from (select max(id) as iid
                            from indexing_log
                           group by company_id,
                                 "date") mids
                   where id = mids.iid
                 )
```

Comment: Apart from slight syntax error (`select **something** from`) this will delete nothing as there will always exist an id.

Comment: It appeared to be even slower =(

Comment: @free2use now check d solution.

Comment: The MAX() in the subquery is not needed (except in mysql;-). See @Roman Pekar's solution.

Comment: "NOT EXISTS is always faster than NOT IN". That absolute statement is not accurate. Run enough benchmarks and you will see that your assertion in inaccurate.

Comment: @bma Absolutely. `NOT EXISTS` is *usually* faster than `NOT IN`, but not always. It's easier to make it *correct* due to the null handling issue though.